# Calling an embedded installer in NSIS on UAC with timeout

Tags: timeout, nsis, uac

I have an NSIS installer which has 'RequestExecutionLevel user'. That installer contains an embedded NSIS installer which has 'RequestExecutionLevel admin'. This child installer is only called in certain scenarios. This was done so that certain admin operations could be contained in the child installer and the user would only be prompted for UAC approval when nessacary.

My question is, how can I invoke the child installer so that:
a) the user will be prompted with the UAC dialog (if UAC is enabled), and
b) the child installer will be terminated if the user does not click Yes or No within a given time period.

I have been using ShellExecWait (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellExecWait), which works well, but does not provide the option to specify a timeout value (i.e. it will wait forever).

Note that I have already tried using the following NSIS functions:
* ShellExecWait - Does not allow timeout
* ExecWait - The child installer fails as it inherits the parent installer's execution level.
* ExecShell - Does not allow timeout
* nsExec::Exec - The child installer fails as it inherits the parent installer's execution level.

I'm getting pretty desperate here - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UAC is not designed to support this and any attempt to do this should be considered a hack!

Part of the problem is that ShellExecuteEx in your process is part of the elevation operation so it cannot be killed without killing the thread or process. To work around this I allow the setup to act as a middle man that we can kill. One flaw with this design is that the UAC dialog stays around after the timeout has killed the process (The UAC GUI is in consent.exe running as SYSTEM) This means that the user could elevate the child installer after your main installer is gone! I only tested this on Win7 and there UAC does not start a new process if the parent is gone but this could be a bug or at least the behavior is not documented AFAIK and probably not something that should be used in production code!

```
Outfile "test.exe"
RequestExecutionlevel User

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

Page Instfiles

!macro ElevateWithTimeout_OnInit
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} $0 '--ExecTimer' $1
${If} $1 != ""
    StrCpy $1 $0 "" 12
    ExecShell 'runas' $1 ;RunAs is not really required as long as the .exe has a manifest that requests elevation...
    Quit
${EndIf}
!macroend
Function ElevateWithTimeout
InitPluginsDir
System::Call '*(&i60,tsr1)i.r0'
StrCpy $1 "--ExecTimer $1"
System::Call '*$0(i 60,i 0x40,i $HwndParent,i0,t"$ExePath",tr1,to,i1)i.r0'
System::Call 'shell32::ShellExecuteEx(ir0)i.r1'
System::Call '*$0(i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i.r2)'
System::Free $0
Pop $0 ; Timeout (MS)
${If} $1 <> 0
    System::Call 'kernel32::WaitForSingleObject(ir2,ir0)i.r0'
    ${If} 0x102 = $0 ;WAIT_TIMEOUT
        System::Call 'kernel32::TerminateProcess(ir2,i666)'
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call 'kernel32::CloseHandle(ir2)'
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
!insertmacro ElevateWithTimeout_OnInit
FunctionEnd

Section
Push 30000
Push "regedit.exe"
call ElevateWithTimeout
SectionEnd
```

To create a safer more robust solution the child installer would have to be in on the game and know when to abort itself if the parent is gone but doing that in pure NSIS code is way too much work.

I would probably recommend that you drop the timeout requirement and use `RequestExecutionlevel highest` in the outer installer and only run the child if you are admin (`UserInfo::GetAccountType`).